# Preventing form submission with Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a Dojo SubmitButton with jsId="saveParamButtonWidget". I overrided its onClick method by putting:

```
saveParamButtonWidget.onClick = editParam
```

I defined the editParam() function like this:

```
function editParam(eventObj) {
    dojo.stopEvent(eventObj);
    // ...
}
```

dojo.stopEvent() is supposed to stop event bubbling and default processing. However, the browser will submit the form anyway. I also tried with the following:

```
function editParam(eventObj) {
    eventObj.stopPropagation();
    eventObj.preventDefault();
    // ...
}
```

Same thing. The only way I've managed to prevent form submission is by returning "false" from the event handler:

```
function editParam(eventObj) {
    // ...
    return false;
}
```

Can someone tell me why the first two ways did not work? Thanks.

Comment: Please give more information:what type of widget did you use (full name), dojo doesn't know a "SubmitButton", i suppose this is a dijit.form.Button, with the type "submit". A code snippet would help a lot

Comment: I'm sorry, I was using Zend Framework's Dojo submit element, which is called SubmitButton. But you are right, it is a dijit.form.Button with the type "submit".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Okay, after doing some digging through the source, I believe I can answer your question definitively.

The reason `dojo.stopEvent()` doesn't work, but `return false` does, is entirely due to how `dijit.form.Button` is coded.  If you're interested, it's time for a little field trip.  Keep your hard hats on.

When a `dijit.form.Button` is clicked...

1. The button's `_onButtonClick` method is invoked.  (This is hooked up in the template, to the special `ondijitclick` event which captures not only mouse click but also certain keypresses, for a11y purposes.)
2. The `_onButtonClick` method first invokes the `_onClick` method, which, presuming the button is not disabled (which it's not in this case), invokes *and returns the result of* the `onClick` method.  This is of particular interest since it's the method you're overriding!
3. Coming back to `_onButtonClick`, if `_onClick` returned *precisely* `false` (e.g. if your `onClick` handler returned `false`), `_onButtonClick` *immediately bails out*.  **This is why returning false makes your code work as desired.** But what happens if it *doesn't* bail out there?  Let's follow the trail further...
4. Next, `_onButtonClick` checks whether this button *not* a descendant of an actual HTML form, but *is* a descendant of a widget with an `_onSubmit` method (duck-typing).  I'm assuming that in your case it *is* inside a *real* form (`dijit.form.Form` counts), so we'll skip over this.  (I am under the impression that this code path wouldn't actually end up submitting, whereas yours apparently does.)
5. One final condition is checked: if the button has a `valueNode` defined (it does), the `click` method of this node is invoked.  Unfortunately, this produces an *entirely new event object* on an invisible `input type="submit"` node under your form, and thus anything you tried to tell the original event is rendered immaterial, and the form goes on to submit!  **This is why `dojo.stopEvent` did not work - this code in `dijit.form.Button` pays it absolutely no heed.**

I cooked this up as a somewhat-limited proof of concept (be sure to open firebug/etc. to get the logs): http://jsfiddle.net/Bf5H8/

Perhaps this is something that should be logged as a bug, but I suppose the initial thought may have been that supporting the well-known `return false` mechanism would be enough.

All this being said, it's quite possible that overriding onSubmit of the form is more in-line with your interests than overriding the button's onClick anyway (as S.Jones suggested), but at least this should solve the mystery.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, Ken.

Comment: I checked with Doug on this, it is by design.   As your analysis showed, it would be troublesome to support stopEvent() since there are two event objects.    Another example of where you need to return false is from the onSubmit method in a form.   In that case there isn't even an event object to call stopEvent() on.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. +1

I believe you have to use `dojo.connect` to connect your function to a DOM event to get access to those methods with an event object.

See: [The Event Object (DojoTollkit.org Reference Guide)](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/events.html#id5)

> **The Event Object**
>
> When you connect a function to a DOM
>   event with dojo.connect,
>   Dojo passes your function a normalized
>   event object. This means that,
>   regardless of the client's browser,
>   you can count on a set of standard
>   attributes about the event and a set
>   of methods to manipulate the event.
>
> Assume that your function has been
>   called by dojo.connect and takes an
>   argument named *event*, like:
>
> ```
> dojo.connect(dojo.byId("node"), "onclick", function(event){
>     // the var 'event' is available, and is the normalized object 
> });
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Dojo normalizes the following methods with an event object:
>
> - event.preventDefault — prevent an event's default behavior (e.g., a link from loading a new page)
> - event.stopPropagation — prevent an event from triggering a parent node's event
>
> Additionally, dojo.stopEvent(event)
>   will prevent both default behavior any
>   any propagation (bubbling) of an
>   event.

---

That said, placing a function like the one below in your form to perform some logic before submitting it, is a fairly clean, easily understood & maintainable approach.

```
<script type="dojo/method" event="onSubmit">
    if (!this.validate()) { // or whatever else you'd like to evaluate
        // insert calls here...
        return false;
    }
    return true;
<script>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Technically nothing bad will happen from setting the onClick method directly, since it's just a stub in `dijit._Widget` meant to be hooked anyway.  In fact, using dojo.connect (or perhaps better, yourwidget.connect) will actually do *worse* because then `return false` won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for using dojo.stopEvent

This issue is solved the form submission issue like this - here it is a simple form used to connect through dojo:

```
this.formId = dojo.byId("formId");
dojo.connect(this.formId, 'onsubmit', function(evt) {
    var val_main = validate_this_form(0);
       if(val_main == false)
           dojo.stopEvent(evt);
});
```