# Dojo ajax call returns before Java code completes?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, google-chrome, dojo

I have a problem with a Struts2 + dojo web application that I've inherited.  The application works in IE9 and Firefox but does not work in Chrome.

Here is the submit button code:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" 
        type="submit" 
        onclick="sendRuleForm('requestSubmitForm', 'resultDiv', 'RequestSubmit.action');">Submit</button>
```

Here is the javascript code for the sendRuleForm function above:

```
function sendRuleForm(formId, id, actionNm) {
    var bindArgs = {
        url: actionNm,
        form: document.getElementById(formId),
        handleAs: "text",
        load: function(data) {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data;            
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            return;
        }
    }
    dojo.xhrPost(bindArgs);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ajaxLoader;
}
```

I noticed that if I set breakpoints in my Java code, the web page returns with an error even **before** the action even completes.

Chrome Developer Tools indicate a status of cancelled for the action/request ( [What does status=canceled for a resource mean in Chrome Developer Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009423/what-does-status-canceled-for-a-resource-mean-in-chrome-developer-tools) )

I am using an older version of dojo 1.3.1 but updating it to the latest version did not fix the problem.

Can anyone explain this behavior and let me know how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: what happens if you open the request in a tab?

Comment: @mschr Not sure what you mean by that. Can you please clarify?

Comment: rightclick the status = cancelled line in developer tools, select 'open link in new tab'

Comment: Neat! Didn't realize I could do that. I get a null pointer error in the code where it was expecting an empty String variable (as typically set by Struts2 framework)

Comment: @mschr And of course, I can't seem to replicate the behavior documented in my previous comment. When I tried opening the request in a new tab this morning, the app redirects me to a different page now because it can't find something it expects in the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rule out the ajax / javascript bit of this error. It is either

1. a bug in chrome (unlikely)
2. a bug in the struts page youre calling, may send back a weird HTTP response (check server logs)
3. there's a 'jitter' in form submission, where multiple requests are sent. im guessing, but maybe `<button type="submit"` and `<input type="submit"` is handled differently in chrome

What youre experiencing in the redirect to a different page is probably due to the fact that Struts Application receives a GET when you manually refresh the URL field in the new tab. Could also be due to a missing login-cookie or such.

To have a true response from the application, try put in the `target` attribute with your `form` and then submit in a normal fashion (without XHR).

```
<form action="RequestSubmit.action" method="POST" target="_debugwin">
    <input type="submit" value="DebugSubmit" name="debugbutton" />
     ... remainder of form code
```

Also, your dijit Button has an overridable function 'onClick', note the camelCasing. Youre setting the DOM onclick event. In this case, youre click event may get handled by the browser immediately after the dojo.xhr fires (when function returns). See this Q: [Preventing form submission with Dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844995/preventing-form-submission-with-dojo)

Only way, however, for this to be the case - and at same time you seeing the 'Cancelled' error in debug window is, if the form is loaded in a (i)frame. Otherwise the full page would refresh and network monitoring would reset. As an easy, win-win workaround, adapt the onclick attribute as follows:

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" 
        type="submit" 
        onClick="sendRuleForm('requestSubmitForm', 'resultDiv', 'RequestSubmit.action'); /* NOTE */ return false;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Adding the `return false;` to the onClick code fixed the issue for me.  Thanks for the thorough answer.

Comment: cheers :) threw me off at first, bcuz form submit button reloads the page and normally resets the developer network tab contents